# Best practice to write a function or functions with generic type argument with default value of null

Tags: c#, syntax, api-design

Say, I have a function with generic type argument with default value of null. For example, the signature of the function is

`public T CallFunction<T,K>(K value = null) where K : class`

So, when we call this function using the default value, it looks a bit weird.

`string result = CallFunction<string, MyClass>()`

The `MyClass` actually can be any class, since it is null. And we cannot skip it as `string result = CallFunction<string>()`. It will throw compiler error, specifically CS0305.

To avoid this weird situation, for example, my solution is adding a direct function of `public T CallFunction<T>()`. This results in code duplication. (For some reasons, I cannot add a private function for both). I wonder if we have a better API design?

Comment: You could just make an overload which passes through eg `public T CallFunction<T>() => CallFunction<T, string>();`

Comment: Overloads, you can also do them as extension method to keep it away from your meaningful code base. Wether or not it´s "best practice" is debatable. Many libraries do this, but that does not mean you have to. For instance here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnectionExtensions.cs you can see the bajillion overload of "On" in the signalr client implementation.

Comment: I think a pass-through is best. `public T CallFunction<T, null>()` really should be a `public T CallFunction<T>`, at minimum just for clarity sake. But there is nothing wrong with a pass-through. You only other alt is the wrap the shared logic into another method, and have both overloads call that method, but that is pointless imo.

Comment: @Max the provided method signature does not specify that this is a `static` method, so I don't agree that it can be a extension method if its dependent on any sort of state from the class object that it is within

Comment: You can extend non static functions just fine. The only thing you cannot do in an extension function is access private instance variables/functions of the class you are extending. But we are talking about a function that will call another public function in a nicer way it probably wont need to. The 397 lines of extension functions i´ve linked extend a non static class too.

Comment: Imo, just depends as stated those are 397 lines of extensions just for one method. Those are not even all the extensions they ship, there are more. It can get huge real fast in c# if you want to achieve maximum syntax sugar for the user of your library. You may just not need the additional syntax sugar for that method at all, or if you determine you do it may be few enough to keep it all in the same class. But if you scale it up to a bigger library you will benefit from splitting implementation methods from those that just call stuff in other more different ways.

Comment: @Max Why add it as an extension method when you have the class source code right in front of you? Extension methods are for adding methods to types without creating a new, derived type or recompiling the code for an existing type. Generally it's better to make the method a first-class citizen of the type if possible.

Comment: I explained why you would want to do so and that you may not need to if your use case is small enough. There are a lot of these cases (like the one I linked) where you end up with many hundreds of lines of overloads that do add zero actual functionality to the class and just make it easier / more convenient to call. At that point, I would say no you do not want that in the same file because it makes it harder than it needs to be to read the meaningful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best practice for the case like that.
However the best solution I see here is do something like this:

```
public TResult CallFunction<TResult, TValue>(TValue value = null) where TValue : class
{
    // your code here
}

public T CallFunction<T>() => CallFunction<T, object>();
```

Then you could call just

```
var result = CallFunction<string>();
or 
var result = CallFunction<string, {some type}>(value);
```

Hope it helps